# how to install py2cairo on ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: python

the README file said：

```
Dependencies
------------
cairo   >= 1.10.0
Python  >= 2.6
```

it seems that I need to install cairo first. but how to install the 'cairo'?

thanks for your help. I installed the libcairo2. but there are still some errors when I execute command 'sudo python waf configure':

```
barry@ubuntu:~/graphite/py2cairo$ sudo python waf configure
  ./options()
 Setting top to                           : /home/barry/graphite/py2cairo 
 Setting out to                           : /home/barry/graphite/py2cairo/build_directory 
 ./configure()
 Checking for 'gcc' (c compiler)          : ok 
 Checking for program python              : /usr/bin/python 
 Checking for python version              : (2, 7, 3, 'final', 0) 
 Checking for library python2.7           : not found 
 Checking for library python2.7           : not found 
 Checking for library python2.7           : yes 
 Checking for program python2.7-config    : not found 
 Checking for program python-config-2.7   : not found 
 Checking for header Python.h             : yes 
 Checking for program pkg-config          : /usr/bin/pkg-config 
 Checking for 'cairo' >= 1.10.2           : not found 
 The configuration failed
(complete log in /home/barry/graphite/py2cairo/build_directory/config.log)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the fullname of the packet in Ubuntu and then install it:

```
apt-cache search libcairo2
apt-get install libcairo2
```

Comment: thanks for your help. I installed the libcairo2. but there are still some errors when I execute command 'sudo python waf configure':

Comment: do you know why these errors happen, need I configure some environment variables?

Comment: Sorry,the error message is to long to edit here, I re-edited the question, and added the errors to it.
  but so far, I have resolved the errors.
  I use 'sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev' instead of 'apt-get install libcairo2'. Then the configuration works.  
  but the build step fail：  
  `c: src/cairomodule.c -> build_directory/src/cairomodule.c.1.o  
../src/cairomodule.c:33:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory`

Comment: you need to install python header files: `apt-get install python-dev`

Comment: thanks for your help again, and sorry for trouble you again. after 'apt-get install python-dev', I have built successful and install successful.  but the when I `import cairo` I got `ImportError: No module named cairo`

Comment: In what directory have you installed it?

Comment: And my `sys.path` value is: `['', '/home/barry/test/demo/fad', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']`

Comment: add to this list path to the cairo installation directory

Comment: but the list path has already contain '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cairo' is not this one?

Comment: `_cairo.so  __init__.py  __init__.pyc  __init__.pyo`

Comment: Try to add `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to `sys.path`.